# How do I update a reactive value in shiny application?

Tags: r, shiny, lapply, reactive

So I have the following shiny app, I am trying to write different functions so I don't have to write repeated lines but I'm getting stuck with updating the scores table in the scores tab. I'm getting the following error when I run the code: Warning: Error in [[: Can't read output 'score_q2ii'.

library(shiny);library(stringr);library(dplyr)

```
questions_df <- data.frame(
  tab = c(rep("Tab1", 2), rep("Tab2", 2)),
  id = c("q1i", "q1ii", "q2i", "q2ii"),
  question = c("Question 1", "Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 2"),
  part = c("i", "ii", "i", "ii"),
  choices = c("1,2,3", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


# Split the questions data frame based on the tab
questions_split <- split(questions_df, questions_df$tab)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Customized Survey using Data Frame"),
  
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Tab1", 
             uiOutput("questions_ui_Tab1"),
             textAreaInput("feedback_Tab1", "Additional feedback:", "", width = "100%", height = "100px"),
             actionButton("submit_Tab1", "Submit Tab1 Answers")
    ),
    tabPanel("Tab2", 
             uiOutput("questions_ui_Tab2"),
             textAreaInput("feedback_Tab2", "Additional feedback:", "", width = "100%", height = "100px"),
             actionButton("submit_Tab2", "Submit Tab2 Answers")
    ),
    tabPanel("Score Table", tableOutput("score_table"))
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Reactive value to store scores and feedbacks
  scores <- reactiveVal(data.frame(id = questions_df$id, score = numeric(nrow(questions_df)), feedback = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  
  render_question_ui <- function(tab) {
    output[[paste0("questions_ui_", tab)]] <- renderUI({
      question_list <- lapply(split(questions_split[[tab]], questions_split[[tab]]$question), generate_ui)
      do.call(tagList, question_list)
    })
  }
  
  render_question_ui("Tab1")
  render_question_ui("Tab2")
  generate_ui <- function(question_subset) {
    tags$div(
      h3(unique(question_subset$question)),
      tags$ul(
        lapply(1:nrow(question_subset), function(i) {
          tags$li(
            paste0("Part ", question_subset$part[i], ") "),
            radioButtons(question_subset$id[i], NULL, 
                         choices = strsplit(question_subset$choices[i], ",")[[1]], 
                         selected = NULL),
            if(question_subset$part[i]!='i') {
              tags$div("Requires evidence?",
                       selectInput(paste0("e", question_subset$id[i]), NULL, 
                                   choices = c("No" = 1, "Yes" = 2, "Partially Accepted" = 1.5), 
                                   selected = NULL),
                       tags$br()
              )
            },
            "Score for this part: ", textOutput(paste0("score_", question_subset$id[i]))
            
          )
        })
      )
    )
  }
  
  lapply(1:nrow(questions_df), function(i) {
    observe({
      
      evidence_input<-input[[paste0("e", questions_df$id[i])]]
      level_input <- as.numeric(input[[questions_df$id[i]]])
      
      output[[paste0("score_", questions_df$id[i])]] <- renderText({
        if (questions_df$part[i] == "i") {
          level_input * 0.5
        } else {
          level_input *10* as.numeric(evidence_input)
        }
      })
      
      current_scores <- scores()
      current_scores[current_scores$id == questions_df$id[i], "score"] <- as.numeric(output[[paste0("score_", questions_df$id[i])]]())
      scores(current_scores)
      
    })
  })
  
  # Render the table
  output$score_table <- renderTable({
    scores()
  }, rownames = TRUE)
  
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be this line:  `current_scores[current_scores$id == questions_df$id[i], "score"] <- as.numeric(output[[paste0("score_", questions_df$id[i])]]())`

A work around is shown below.

```
questions_df <- data.frame(
  tab = c(rep("Tab1", 2), rep("Tab2", 2)),
  id = c("q1i", "q1ii", "q2i", "q2ii"),
  question = c("Question 1", "Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 2"),
  part = c("i", "ii", "i", "ii"),
  choices = c("1,2,3", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


# Split the questions data frame based on the tab
questions_split <- split(questions_df, questions_df$tab)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Customized Survey using Data Frame"),
  
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Tab1", 
             uiOutput("questions_ui_Tab1"),
             textAreaInput("feedback_Tab1", "Additional feedback:", "", width = "100%", height = "100px"),
             actionButton("submit_Tab1", "Submit Tab1 Answers")
    ),
    tabPanel("Tab2", 
             uiOutput("questions_ui_Tab2"),
             textAreaInput("feedback_Tab2", "Additional feedback:", "", width = "100%", height = "100px"),
             actionButton("submit_Tab2", "Submit Tab2 Answers")
    ),
    tabPanel("Score Table", tableOutput("score_table"))
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Reactive value to store scores and feedbacks
  scores <- reactiveValues(df = data.frame(id = questions_df$id, score = numeric(nrow(questions_df)), feedback = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  
  lapply(1:nrow(questions_df), function(i) {
    observe({
      
      evidence_input<-input[[paste0("e", questions_df$id[i])]]
      level_input <- as.numeric(input[[questions_df$id[i]]])
      if (questions_df$part[i] == "i") {
        mylevel <- level_input * 0.5
      } else {
        mylevel <- level_input *10* as.numeric(evidence_input)
      }
      
      if (!is.null(input[[questions_df$id[i]]])){
        output[[paste0("score_", questions_df$id[i])]] <- renderText({
          mylevel
        })
        
        current_scores <- scores$df
        # current_scores[current_scores$id == questions_df$id[i], "score"] <- as.numeric(output[[paste0("score_", questions_df$id[i])]]())
        current_scores[current_scores$id == questions_df$id[i], "score"] <- mylevel
        scores$df <- current_scores
      }
      
      
    })
  })

  render_question_ui <- function(tab) {
    output[[paste0("questions_ui_", tab)]] <- renderUI({
      question_list <- lapply(split(questions_split[[tab]], questions_split[[tab]]$question), generate_ui)
      do.call(tagList, question_list)
    })
  }
  
  render_question_ui("Tab1")
  render_question_ui("Tab2")
  generate_ui <- function(question_subset) {
    tags$div(
      h3(unique(question_subset$question)),
      tags$ul(
        lapply(1:nrow(question_subset), function(i) {
          tags$li(
            paste0("Part ", question_subset$part[i], ") "),
            radioButtons(question_subset$id[i], NULL, 
                         choices = strsplit(question_subset$choices[i], ",")[[1]], 
                         selected = NULL),
            if(question_subset$part[i]!='i') {
              tags$div("Requires evidence?",
                       selectInput(paste0("e", question_subset$id[i]), NULL, 
                                   choices = c("No" = 1, "Yes" = 2, "Partially Accepted" = 1.5), 
                                   selected = NULL),
                       tags$br()
              )
            },
            "Score for this part: ", textOutput(paste0("score_", question_subset$id[i]))
            
          )
        })
      )
    )
  }
  
  # Render the table
  output$score_table <- renderTable({
    scores$df
  }, rownames = TRUE)
  
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you tell me what I was doing wrong? I see the changes you made but I'm not sure what I need to do next time

Comment: Initially `input[[questions_df$id[i]]]` is `NULL`.  You need to account for that. Try `print(input[[questions_df$id[i]]])` in a reactive environment to see how it changes when you run your code.